Kysely + Prisma and postgresql enum types
Is there a way to use enum types in Kysely query conditions.
I have enum types defined in prisma schema.
enum MyEnumb {
  VALUE1
  VALUE2
}

model Model1 {
  id            Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  col1          MyEnumb
}

When I attempt to use MyEnumb in conditions, I get en error.
 await prisma.$kysely
    .selectFrom("Model1")
    .where("Model1.col1", "=", MyEnumb.VALUE1)
    .select(["id"])
    .execute();


The error:
ERROR: operator does not exist: "Model1" = text

Are there any workarounds except raw queries?
